# How to embed our own custom start card like youtube with metadata on share of video?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to show custom play Icon inspite of facebook regular playionc when a user shares video from website. Currently I saw Youtube does this, How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Startcard is the one which you on facebook when we share a video with some Image, title etc.

Comment: Hi WizKid, in simple, how to keep our play icon for the shared video player. Now, FB is always overriding it's play icon.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible to provide our own start card, the only thing we can control is image and text which will be displayed on the startcard